# Android twitter application error

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using this code : https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample

I replace `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` accordingly but I am still getting the error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken

Can anybody explain why it is giving me error?

Comment: where you put the jar file in your project?

Comment: i created a lib folder in project and put there all files. Actually i am directly using the project which is mentioned in above link and in that project it contains in lib folder.

Comment: create libs folder instead of lib

Comment: same project is working fine when i checked

Comment: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter you can check this one

Comment: i tried ur solution but still am getting force close. Can u tell me the function of CallBack URL what is use of that? Now i m getting at that line

Comment: after getting the access token twitter app redirect to callback url and in Manifest your activity must be the intent-filter for that callback url. Are yor tried given link?

Comment: yes i tried ur link. here i just put my twitter_consumer_key, twitter_secret_key. and run the program it giving me error on this line: mTwitter  = new TwitterApp(this, twitter_consumer_key,twitter_secret_key); is my keys are wrong? can i show my keys to u?

Comment: Don't reveal the key. Did you add a callback url?

Comment: No.I think there is no need to add callback url.

Comment: plz help me. I m not getting what exactly i m doing wrong... :(

Comment: @neha in my link you need to replace your key and secret in two file  TestPost.java and TestConnect.java

Comment: @Vivek i do the changes in both the classes still there is  same error on same line

Comment: and about the callback url. My callback url is None. so how should i specify it in manifest file?

Comment: CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://connect"

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava finally  i am able to run ur program :) But am not able to lo-gin thr. Actually i am not found any option to login. whenever i typed something in edit box and click on submit button toast appears with msg "review posted" but where that review posted exactly? I cant find it in my account.

Comment: in your project you are getting AccessToken, So now can you review your code and use AccessToken for further process

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava m not getting point. how can i use AccessToken?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com// this link will be helpful for you to understand the basis of twitter api

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava hey finally i am able to run your app :) Thank you so much for your continuous help. you really helped me alot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the Solution. This may be helpful to someone who is using above link. Create a libs folder add all jar file there. After that register your app on twitter obtain consumer key, secrete key and callback url form there. paste it in ur code. Remember also change callback url in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Jars, then choose your library.